# How to Scale and Center UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I am working with BezierPath and could make a basic star shape within a view successfully, it works great. However, the view's size can be changeable. And I cannot center this bezier path when the view size is changed, I managed to scale it but getting center was hard to me.

[image]
[image: image2]

```
private func pointFrom(_ angle: CGFloat, radius: CGFloat, offset: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: radius * cos(angle) + offset.x, y: radius * sin(angle) + offset.y)//CGPointMake(radius * cos(angle) + offset.x, radius * sin(angle) + offset.y)
}

private func generateStar(width:CGFloat, height:CGFloat, radius:CGFloat) -> CAShapeLayer{
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    var scale = width / height
    if width > height{
        scale = height / width
    }

    let starExtrusion:CGFloat = 60.0

    let center = CGPoint(x: width / 2.0, y: height / 2.0)

    let pointsOnStar = 5

    var angle:CGFloat = -CGFloat(.pi / 2.0)
    let angleIncrement = CGFloat(.pi * 2.0 / Double(pointsOnStar))
    let radius = width / 2.0

    var firstPoint = true

    for _ in 1...pointsOnStar {

        let point = pointFrom(angle, radius: radius, offset: center)
        let nextPoint = pointFrom(angle + angleIncrement, radius: radius, offset: center)
        let midPoint = pointFrom(angle + angleIncrement / 2.0, radius: starExtrusion, offset: center)

        if firstPoint {
            firstPoint = false
            path.move(to: point)
        }

        path.addLine(to: midPoint)//addLineToPoint(midPoint)
        path.addLine(to: nextPoint)//addLineToPoint(nextPoint)

        angle += angleIncrement
    }
    path.apply(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
    path.close()

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path.cgPath

    return maskLayer
}
```

How can I manage to make that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The center of your path moves with this command:

```
path.apply(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
```

To keep your `center` in the center, scale it by `1 / scale` so that when it is scaled by `scale`, it will end up in the center of the view (since `(1 / scale) * scale == 1`):

Change:

```
let center = CGPoint(x: width / 2.0, y: height / 2.0)
```

to:

```
let center = CGPoint(x: width / 2.0 / scale, y: height / 2.0 / scale)
```

The two scalings cancel each other and the center of the path then ends up where it was originally calculated to be.

---

That said, you are shrinking your star when `height != width`.  You might get a better result if you forget about the scaling and just choose the minimum of `width` and `height` for your `radius` calculation:

Get rid of `scale`, or set it to `1.0`, then

Change:

```
let radius = width / 2.0
```

to:

```
let radius = min(width, height) / 2.0
```

That will let the star be as large as possible while still fitting fully within the view.

---

As you noticed, the star gets "fat" (more circular) as it gets smaller.  This is because you have a hard-coded constant of `60.0` for `starExtrusion`.  That value should be based upon the `radius`.

Set `starExtrusion` after calculating `radius`:

```
let radius = min(width, height) / 2.0
let starExtrusion = radius * 0.4
```

You can vary the `0.4` multiplier to alter the shape of the star.

Comment: I tried but it did not work, can you share fully code, maybe I did smth wrong.

Comment: I suggested two different things. Did you try each one  and did neither work?

Comment: Can you share your full code? For instance, what is `pointFrom()`?

Comment: I updated the answer to be clearer about what I changed.  Both of my suggestions worked with your code.

Comment: Sorry for the latency, I've just updated the full code. I tried the second solution, it worked about scaling and centering. But, for example, when the ratio of the view is 2:1, the star's shape is not a star anymore. It changed to like a circle.

Comment: Your star is misshapen because you have a constant value of `60.0` for `starExtrusion`.  It should be calculated based upon the value of `radius`.  You can set the multiplier to get the star shape you want; `0.4` works well.  Set `starExtrusion` after calculating the `radius` with: `let starExtrusion = radius * 0.4`

Comment: I rolled back your question to the original version but with the `pointFrom()` function added.  It fouls up the Q&A when the code in the question is changed to include suggestions from an answer.  Someone reading this later would be confused why my answer is talking about `scaling` when your code doesn't include it and suggesting making `radius = min(width, height) / 2.0` when your code already does that.

Comment: Yes, you are definitely right, the problem is all about the extrusion. Since I calculated the starExtrusion dynamically, now it has been working. Thanks for the latest update.

Answer (score 1):

UIView's `layoutSubviews` got called when resized, you can reset the mask by overriding that method.

Comment: I already call layoutSubviews, but the problem is how to reset the mask? Because the mask is only working if the width and the height are equal.